# Azure Logic apps - output array in email body

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have trouble using my array variable in my V2 email in Logic apps. I would like to output my array in the email body. For example if my array is ["1","2",3"]. Im want each value on its own row.

1

2

3

I have 2 issues, outputting my array in the email body(only strings showing in the dynamic menu) and making each value on a row.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you need to generate the string for the body of the email.  That will require looping over the array.  It's not magic, it doesn't know that you want the array broken out to separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement by replacing "," with "< br>< br>" while sending the email using `Send an email (V2)` action. Below is the expression that worked for me.

```
replace(string(variables('SampleArray')),',','<br><br>')
```

Here is the flow of my Logic App

[image]

***Result in my Inbox:***

[image]

To reproduce the same, you can use below codeview in your logicapp

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "SampleArray": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "SampleArray",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                1,
                                2,
                                3
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{replace(string(variables('SampleArray')),',','<br><br>')}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Sample",
                        "To": "<YOUR-EMAIL>"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "operationOptions": "DisableAutomaticDecompression",
                "runAfter": {
                    "SampleArray": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```